# PostgreSQL Default Result Limit

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I'm using Grafana and PostgreSQL 13 for visualizing. There are many users in the Grafana and they could send queries to their own databases.

I need to set a default result limit for sent queries. (Like 1000) But I couldn't find a solution. I analyzed the PgPool to rewrite the query but I think it couldn't do that.

Is there any solution for that? I'm not sure but maybe I need a TCP Proxy which can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular solution, as far as I know, is [PgBouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/). PgBouncer is a lightweight connection pooler for PostgreSQL. It acts as a Postgres server, so simply point your Grafana and other clients to the PgBouncer port.

Here are some installation guides for Linux (Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS):

- [A Guide to Using pgBouncer for PostgreSQL](https://severalnines.com/blog/guide-using-pgbouncer).
- [PostgreSQL Connection Pooling with PgBouncer](https://pgdash.io/blog/pgbouncer-connection-pool.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. PgBouncer has a TCP Package Size limit. It seems a solution for me. I integrated it into the production and everything seems good.